# Differentiating the matrix with exponential function?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to show that

$$ae^{\lambda t}(1,0)+be^{\lambda t}(t,1)$$ is a general solution of

$$
X'=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}X
$$

I guess that the derivative of the first part is just $a \lambda e^{\lambda t } (1.0)$, but I am not sure how to differentiate the second part.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Write the solutions as

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& ae^{\lambda t} + b t e^{\lambda t} \\
y(t) &=& be^{\lambda t}
\end{eqnarray}

And show they solve the problem

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& \lambda x(t) + y(t) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& \lambda y(t)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hi, to show that this is a general solution, is it required to show that this is unique solution as well?

Comment: @rake No, just show it is a solution

Answer (score 1):

Well, for *general solution* of 
$$ 
X'=MX
$$
($M$ a constant matrix), the technique is always the same.

1. consider an invertible solution (i.e. not zero !) of 
   $$ 
   C'=MC
   $$
   (with $C$ matrices with variable coefficients) like $C=e^{tM}$

   The general solution is of the form $X=e^{tM}X_0$ where $X_0$ is the "initial vector" (i.e. at $t=0$).

Here your "multiplier" is 
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and, taking into account that scalar matrices ($\lambda I$) commute with everybody, you can apply $e^{A+B}=e^{A}e^{B}$ when $A,B$ commute. Then
$$
e^{tM}=e^{\begin{bmatrix} t\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & t\lambda\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}=
e^{\begin{bmatrix} t\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & t\lambda\end{bmatrix}}
e^{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}=
\begin{bmatrix} e^{t\lambda} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{t\lambda}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} e^{t\lambda} & te^{t\lambda} \\ 0 & e^{t\lambda}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

---

Note that 
$$be^{\lambda t}\pmatrix {t \\ 1}=be^{\lambda t}(t \pmatrix{ 1 \\0}+ \pmatrix {0 \\ 1})=be^{\lambda t}t \pmatrix{ 1 \\0}+be^{\lambda t} \pmatrix {0 \\ 1}$$

You know how to differentiate that ?